# How to make NumpadAdd output {

Tags: autohotkey

I cannot understand how to make braces { and } be out put by AutoHotKey v2
I write:
NumpadAdd::{ -> does not work
Numpad::{Send {} -> does not work

Its probably super simple, but cant figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Send command or Hotstrings are used in their default
(non-raw) mode, characters such as {}^!+# have special meaning.
To use them literally in these cases, enclose them in
braces:

```
Numpad1::Send "{{}{}}"
```

or use the [raw mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#Raw)

```
Numpad2::Send "{Raw}{}"
```

or the **[Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#Text) (recommended)**:

```
Numpad3::Send "{Text}{}"
```

See also [Escape Sequences](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/misc/EscapeChar.htm)